# xpath for xml extract in Oracle

Tags: xpath, xmltype

Let's imagine that I have a clob field in my database with the follow xml:

```
<Order>
    <createdOn>2015-02-12T16:43:18.424+01:00</createdOn>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <key>Action1</key>
            <value>Yes</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>Action2</key>
            <value>No</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>Action3</key>
            <value>Maybe</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</Order>
```

I need to extract the value for all action3 in this field.

How can I extract this value for all rows that I have if the xpath is with the same name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

```
'//key[text()="Action3"]/../value/text()'
```

With a real command line against a file :

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//key[text()="Action3"]/../value/text()' file.xml
```

Output:

```
Maybe
```

Comment: I forgot to add one importante thing. The xml sometime has more Key tags, as so by position we cannot do it.

Comment: _I can break the rules too !_ - Postfix, born in 1998